# Closure compiler difference between returning void and returning undefined

Tags: javascript, types, google-closure-compiler

In the closure compiler, is there any difference between returning a `void` type versus returning an `undefined` type.

```
/**
* @return {void}
*/
function myFunction() {}


/**
* @return {undefined}
*/
function myFunction2() {}
```

Comment: `void` is an operator in JavaScript, not a type, so I would think it should generate a compiler error. It would make as much sense as `@return {delete}` or `@return {typeof}`.  But after a quick test the compiler seems to be OK with `@return {void}`. Why do you ask? Using `undefined` would be preferred.

Comment: I checked that it does in fact compile without warnings at [closure compiler service](https://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home#code%3D%252F**%250A*%2520%2540return%2520%257Bvoid%257D%250A*%252F%250Afunction%2520myFunction()%2520%257B%257D%250A%250A%250A%252F**%250A*%2520%2540return%2520%257Bundefined%257D%250A*%252F%250Afunction%2520myFunction2()%2520%257B%257D).  I'm curious why it's allowed.  Is it a result of copying Java?

Comment: You might ask on the closure compiler list if you don't get a reply here.  I'm not sure what you mean by "copying Java".  The compiler is very, very good but not perfect.  They have an effort to improve it called "new type inference" but I tried turning that on and it also didn't catch this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@type {void}` means the same thing to Closure Compiler as `@type {undefined}`. Use whichever you like.